# Dynamic data showing undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters

in my project, I'm trying, when I click a blog in many blogs. then only that blog will open in another route. and I set that route dynamically. and trying to load data using the find method. but that showing undefined. Please help me. below are my all codes.

this is my blogs page

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Card, Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import { Pagination } from "swiper";
import "./Blog.css";
import ScrollToTop from "react-scroll-to-top";
import { HashLoader } from "react-spinners";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Blogs = () => {


    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://enigmatic-crag-58614.herokuapp.com/blogs')
            .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data=>setBlogs(data))
    },[])
    console.log(blogs);
    
    


    return (
        <div className="container my-5">
        <ScrollToTop smooth color="#FE1A00" viewBox="0 0 250 250" />
           

            <h1 className="text-danger">Blogs</h1>

            {blogs.length === 0 && (
                <h1 className="my-5 py-5">
                  <HashLoader color={'#FE1A00'} loading={true} size={150} />
                </h1>
              )}
                <Row xs={1} md={3} className="g-4">
                    {
                        blogs.map(blog => <Col>
                            <Card className="shadow">
                                <Card.Img
                                    variant="top"
                                    src={blog.imageLink}
                                    className="m-3"
                                />
                                <Card.Body>
                                    <h3 className="text-danger">{blog.heading}</h3>
                                    <Card.Text>
                                        {blog.text.slice(0, 200)}...
                                    </Card.Text>
                                </Card.Body>
                                <strong className="mb-3">
                                    <Link to={`/single-blog/${blog._id}`} className="see-more">
                                        See More <i className="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>{" "}
                                    </Link>
                                </strong>
                            </Card>
                        </Col>)
                    }
                    
            </Row>
            
        </div>
    );
};

export default Blogs;
```

This is my single blog page

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import "./SingleBlog.css";

const SingleBlog = () => {

    const { id } = useParams;

    const [singleData, setSingleData] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://enigmatic-crag-58614.herokuapp.com/blogs')
            .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setSingleData(data))
    }, [])
    console.log(singleData);

    const matchedData = singleData.find((singleBlogPost) => singleBlogPost?._id == id)

console.log(matchedData);

    return (
        <div className="single-blog container w-75">
            <div className="image-div mb-5 p-0">
                <img
                    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Walking_tiger_female.jpg/220px-Walking_tiger_female.jpg"
                    alt=""
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1 className="text-danger">Tiger</h1>
                <p className="text-start fs-5 fw-700">
                    The tiger (Panthera tigris) is the largest living cat species and a member of
                    the genus Panthera. It is most recognisable for its dark vertical stripes on
                    orange fur with a white underside. An apex predator, it primarily preys on
                    ungulates such as deer and wild boar. It is territorial and generally a solitary
                    but social predator, requiring large contiguous areas of habitat, which support
                    .
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SingleBlog;
```

This is my app.js file

```
import "./App.css";
import Navigation from "./Components/Navigation/Navigation";

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import HomePage from "./Components/HomePage/HomePage";
import AcdmClass from "./Components/AcademicClass/AcdmClass";
import ClassSubject from "./Components/ClassSubjects/ClassSubject";
import Lesson from "./Components/Lesson";
import Footer from "./Components/Footer/Footer";
import Contact from "./Components/Contact/Contact";
import Review from "./Components/Review/Review";
import Blogs from "./Components/Blog/Blogs";
import Signin from "./Components/Signin/Signin";
import Profile from "./Components/Profile/Profile";
import Skills from "./Components/Skills/Skills";
import AuthProvider from "./Contexts/AuthProvider";
import PrivateRoute from "./Components/PrivateRoute/PrivateRoute";
import SingleBlog from "./Components/SingleBlog/SingleBlog";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <AuthProvider>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Navigation></Navigation>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage></HomePage>}></Route>
                        <Route path="home" element={<HomePage></HomePage>}></Route>
                        <Route path="blog" element={<Blogs></Blogs>}></Route>
                        <Route path="contact" element={<Contact></Contact>}></Route>
                        <Route path="skills" element={<Skills />}></Route>
                        <Route path="others" element={<Skills />}></Route>

                        <Route
                            path="/academic-class"
                            element={
                                <PrivateRoute>
                                    <AcdmClass />
                                </PrivateRoute>
                            }
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/academicclass/:classnumber"
                            element={
                                <PrivateRoute>
                                    <ClassSubject />
                                </PrivateRoute>
                            }
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/lesson"
                            element={
                                <PrivateRoute>
                                    <Lesson />
                                </PrivateRoute>
                            }
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/profile"
                            element={
                                <PrivateRoute>
                                    <Profile />
                                </PrivateRoute>
                            }
                        />

                        <Route
                            path="/review"
                            element={
                                <PrivateRoute>
                                    <Review />
                                </PrivateRoute>
                            }
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/single-blog/:id"
                            element={
                                <PrivateRoute>
                                    <SingleBlog />
                                </PrivateRoute>
                            }
                        />
                        <Route path="/sign-in" element={<Signin />} />
                    </Routes>
                    <Footer></Footer>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </AuthProvider>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

But showing this undefined [please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcy3Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in a useEffect like so

```
useEffect(()=>{
if(singleData){
console.log(singleData);

    const matchedData = singleData.find((singleBlogPost) => singleBlogPost?._id == id)

console.log(matchedData);
}
},[singleData,id])
```

As initially singleData will be undefined and will be set after API call.

Answer (score 0):

In react, The state of the component only get updated at the first time, So  you need to tell the react to get the updated state.

In your singleBlog file -

````
const [singleData, setSingleData] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://enigmatic-crag-58614.herokuapp.com/blogs')
            .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setSingleData(data))
    }, [])
    console.log(singleData);

    const matchedData = singleData.find((singleBlogPost) => singleBlogPost?._id == id) //This line will never get the data until you ask the react to update the state (means to update the ```singleData``` array.

console.log(matchedData);
````

So you need  to put the same method inside useEffect, and let the useEffect run whenever the state `singleData` get updated like this ->

```
useEffect(() => {
        const matchedData = singleData.find((singleBlogPost) => 
        singleBlogPost?._id == id)

       console.log(matchedData);
    }, [singleData, id]) //you need to add here all the dependencies, so that whenever these values will change you need to update your singleBlog page.
```

HERE IS YOUR FINAL CODE OF SINGLE BLOG PAGE ->

```
const SingleBlog = () => {

    const { id } = useParams;

    const [singleData, setSingleData] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://enigmatic-crag-58614.herokuapp.com/blogs')
            .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setSingleData(data))
    }, [])

useEffect(() => {
        const matchedData = singleData.find((singleBlogPost) => 
        singleBlogPost?._id == id)

       console.log(matchedData);
    }, [singleData, id])
 

    return (
        <div className="single-blog container w-75">
            <div className="image-div mb-5 p-0">
                <img
                    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Walking_tiger_female.jpg/220px-Walking_tiger_female.jpg"
                    alt=""
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1 className="text-danger">Tiger</h1>
                <p className="text-start fs-5 fw-700">
                    The tiger (Panthera tigris) is the largest living cat species and a member of
                    the genus Panthera. It is most recognisable for its dark vertical stripes on
                    orange fur with a white underside. An apex predator, it primarily preys on
                    ungulates such as deer and wild boar. It is territorial and generally a solitary
                    but social predator, requiring large contiguous areas of habitat, which support
                    .
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SingleBlog;
```